# Jquery Auto login using localStorage

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to implement an auto login for the user by using ***Remember Me*** functionality.

Here's my code. But it doesn't login the users automatically.

```
if (localStorage.getItem("username") != null) {
  var username = localStorage.getItem("username");
  var password = localStorage.getItem("password");
  $('#txtusername').val(username);
  $('#txtpwd').val(password);
  $.post("../../T").done(function (d) {
    location.replace("../.../menu");
  });
} else {
  console.log("Don't have any key inside localStorage");
}
```

I saved the items by using :

```
$('#remember').click(function () {

    $('#btnSignIn').click(function () {
        if ($('#remember').is(':checked')) {
            localStorage.setItem("username", $("#txtusername").val());
            localStorage.setItem("password", $("#txtpwd").val());
            console.log("Items saved !")
        } else {
            localStorage.removeItem("username");
            localStorage.removeItem("password");
        }
    })

});
```

**EDIT**

- How do I direct the user go into *Menu* page after I filled the *text field* ? Doesn't enough to use `location.replace("...` Do I miss something??

Comment: are you getting the `Username` and `Pwd` ?

Comment: @too_cool yea, I did. And also using the `$('#txtusername').val(username);` to fill the `txt`.

Comment: @QuentinRoger I agree with you. I'm just trying to use this alternative :) But my question is it would not login automatically now.

Comment: How are you triggering the function?
Are you getting `"Don't have any key inside localStorage"`?
put a console before `$.post(....` to see if it is triggered. I doubt the function is not called.

Comment: Your $.post don't send the form. You should the the data with $.post.

Comment: @VenomVendor I check my `localStorage` when running the project. It stored. Thus, I remove the items in `localStorage` and then I can get  the `"Don't have any key inside localStorage"`. The console before `$.post(..` is triggered. So, any idea?

Comment: can you show your `post` method more..?and does your normal Login button work? when user enter the uname and pwd manually and hit Login

Comment: does $.post sending pwd & login in the request body?

Comment: @too_cool I'm using `webapi`. The login function is work perfectly in my project. After I filled the _text field_, what should I do next?

Comment: @ThanNgoHoai What do you mean?

Comment: Problem with your request post, you are not sending data in the body see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ under example to send data. Check your `network` tab to see what's being sent in request.

Comment: then why post again Just simulate a button click again... :)

Comment: @VenomVendor So, you mean I can just post after i filled the _usrname_ and _password_ ?? Not doing things like `location.replace(....` ??

Comment: So you are telling me that you are storing passwords in the localstorage. You hate your users, don't you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will be more effective and I decided to use `$.post` for my scenario instead of *trigger* the `login`button again.

```
var username = localStorage.getItem("username");
var password = localStorage.getItem("password");
$('#txtusername').val(username);
$('#txtpwd').val(password);
if(username && password) {
    var userObject = { username: $("#txtuser......  }; //values
    $.post("../../T", userObject)
} else {
    console.log("Don't have any key inside localStorage");
}
```

Thanks for all the replies too..!

Answer (score 3):

Just simulate a `click` on your working Login button

```
var username = localStorage.getItem("username");
var password = localStorage.getItem("password");
$('#txtusername').val(username);
$('#txtpwd').val(password);
if(username && password) {
  $("#loginButton").click(); 
 // Your existing login button...which you use for normal login
} else {
  console.log("Don't have any key inside localStorage");
}
```

Comment: Did You change the button `loginButton` to your login button `ID`

Comment: of course. It still ask me to sign in although the items are already in `localStorage`.

Comment: i know what's the problem :) The `$("#loginButton").click(); ` should be `$("#btnSignIn").trigger("click");` Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

```
var username = localStorage.getItem("username");
var password = localStorage.getItem("password");
if(username != null && password != null) {
  window.location.href = "../.../menu" // Assign your url to location href
} else {
  console.log("Don't have any key inside localStorage");
}
```